# Connecting 2 LED strips and 1 driver

Tags: led, soldering, driver, led-strip, series

[image]I have the following things:

```
1 5w 3in1 LED strip 
1 10w 3in1 LED strip 
1 20w 3in1 Driver
```

The driver has 3 wires in output, 2 in input. The LED strips each have 3 points: +(positive), -1 (negative), -2 (second negative).

I want to connect all three in such a way that all 2 can be lit up.

I do not have much information about this.

Comment: you did not say what you have, so it is almost impossible to guess how to connect the components correctly

Comment: @jsotola oh yes. That was an error in typing

Comment: Can you tell me what other details you need? I'll try providing them.@jsotola

Comment: @jsotola changed it

Comment: please provide a datasheet for each of the components ... if datasheets are not available, then provide a link to any available information about the components ... use the `edit` button to update your question ... do not write info in comment

Comment: Edit your post to add information about the driver or else no one can tell you how to wire it up.